# xcodebuild for release with clean build results in

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, xcodebuild

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme InVenueExperience -sdk iphoneos7.0 -workspace InVenueExperience.xcworkspace -configuration Release -destination OS=7.0,name=iPad clean test
```

This command results in something odd that i'm not expecting.  I'm trying to build the application target using the release configuration.  I want to start out by cleaning things out and then test that result to make sure quality is high.  Note that i am using cocoa pods to manage third party frameworks.

What happens when i run this command:

```
    Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphoneos7.0

2013-12-15 11:10:53.087 xcodebuild[53897:1007] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit-3697/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDeviceKitBase_Utilities.m:503
Details:  Failed to register "/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library/MobileDevices.bundle" with Launch Services, error code: -10811.
Function: __RegisterUTIsIfNeeded_block_invoke
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb8d340e290>{name = (null), num = 1}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
=== CLEAN TARGET Pods-KissXML OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
[BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-KissXML.build
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-KissXML.build

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods-KissXML.a
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods-KissXML.a

=== CLEAN TARGET Pods-JSONModel OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
[BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods-JSONModel.a
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods-JSONModel.a

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-JSONModel.build
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-JSONModel.build

=== CLEAN TARGET Pods-OCMock OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
Check dependencies
[BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods-OCMock.a
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods-OCMock.a

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-OCMock.build
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-OCMock.build

=== CLEAN TARGET Pods-AFNetworking OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
[BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods-AFNetworking.a
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods-AFNetworking.a

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-AFNetworking.build
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-AFNetworking.build

=== CLEAN TARGET Pods-ISO8601DateFormatter OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
[BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods-ISO8601DateFormatter.a
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods-ISO8601DateFormatter.a

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-ISO8601DateFormatter.build
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-ISO8601DateFormatter.build

=== CLEAN TARGET Pods-Pixate OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
[BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods-Pixate.a
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods-Pixate.a

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-Pixate.build
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods-Pixate.build

=== CLEAN TARGET Pods OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
[BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods.build
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods.build

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods.a
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods.a

=== CLEAN TARGET InVenueExperience OF PROJECT InVenueExperience WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
[BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

Create product structure
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/InVenueExperience.app

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/InVenueExperience.app
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/InVenueExperience.app

Clean.Remove clean /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/InVenueExperience.build/Release-iphonesimulator/InVenueExperience.build
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/ethan\ allen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InVenueExperience-axmmgwepnuzpotfumhmidxhgslek/Build/Intermediates/InVenueExperience.build/Release-iphonesimulator/InVenueExperience.build

** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

=== BUILD TARGET Pods-ISO8601DateFormatter OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

=== BUILD TARGET Pods-AFNetworking OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

=== BUILD TARGET Pods-OCMock OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

=== BUILD TARGET Pods-KissXML OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

=== BUILD TARGET Pods-Pixate OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

=== BUILD TARGET Pods-JSONModel OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

** TEST FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
  Check dependencies
  Check dependencies
  Check dependencies
  Check dependencies
  Check dependencies
  Check dependencies
(6 failures)
```

Am i to assume that "test" is forcing this set of VALID_ARCHS?  There is no where in my pods project nor app project that resolves valid archs to these two.

Note also this did work previously and then started bombing so I'm fairly confused on the issue. Ive seen from other stackoverflow questions that the "Failed to register..." error is a bug somewhere and doesn't affect the build overall.

What am i misunderstanding about the process of building a app with all the release configuration values and then testing that package?

Comment: Something to note as i keep going through trial and error...it would appear that the -destination flag is causing the majority of the issues for the output above